# How to get exact latitude and longitude using GPS tracker?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting lat-long using GPS tracker but I am not getting my exact current location what I am getting is location 50 meter away from my current location I am using GPS Tracker only.each and every answer will be appreciable.my location is not getting varied from device to device as per mentioned in previous question.and i did not get any helpful answer their.

Comment: could it be something to do with accuracy ?! ,i hope you know this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't find the exact current location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889834/cant-find-the-exact-current-location-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fused location api of google we can get more exact lat and long but not 100% always.Fused location api is better then GPS tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Use google client api for accurate location

you can refer-
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: i already implemented this example but not getting exact location .thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FusedLocationProviderClient from Google location api
just apply location library in gradle(app level).

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

and at the bottom of app level gradle add this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my code in mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

private static final String TAG="Logs Details";


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     buildGoogleApiClient();
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.e(TAG,"app is connected");

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

}
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            mLastLocation = location;

            Log.e("latitude",location.latitude);
            Log.e("longitude",location.longitude);



        }
    }



};

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: I am using fused API but not getting exact lat long all the time but getting much better then GPS . lat long getting only up to 7 decimal point using fused API can i get decimal point of lat long more then 7 using fused API.

Comment: It will not give always the exact lat lang but it's more accurate as per my experience